# Maximum and argmaximum in Tikzmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

`tikzmath` are several math functions. However, I would like to find the maximum number in a given array and the index where the maximum occurs. How can I do this in `tikzmath`?
Could anyone provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I voted to close because the question (1) shows no effort and leaves too much room for interpretation of what you need. (2) it's your 46th question, so you are familiar with the concept :). Independent of that, it's weird that there is not one accepted answer within the 46 questions.

Comment: My question was Very clear. Or you does not know Basic math. Sorry.